# Flask-socketio with Werkzeug

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

My old code, i use werkzeug run_simple to run application. Now, i need use socketio, how can i change run_simple() to socketio.run().

My old code:

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

from admin import api, frontend

application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend.create_app(), {
'/api': api.create_app()
})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, application, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=False)
```

I tried:

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
from admin import api, frontend

app = frontend.create_app()
application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend.create_app(), {
    '/api': api.create_app()
})

socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, application, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=False)
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=False)
```

but it didnt work. Can anyone help me please !

Comment: Did you try passing `application` to `SocketIO`?

Comment: Flask-SocketIO relies heavily on Flask. Are you using Flask, or just Werkzeug?

Comment: @dirn i tried but didnt work :(.

Comment: @Miguel: both of them.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn The only clear problem I see in your code is that you initialize the socketio extension using `app`, but then put a different instance of the application in the dispatcher middleware. These two should be the same instance. Besides that, I can't really say. It would help if you describe how this isn't working for you, and include any errors or stack traces that you get.

Comment: I am also doing same thing (Trying to use websockets in my project inspired mostly by Flask Overholt). Have you found any solution for your problem. Can you please post your solution here if you have found any ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this is achievable by wrapping and replacing the Flask apps `wsgi_app` attribute as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222848/792406).

```
app = frontend.create_app()

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/api': api.create_app()
})

socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=False)
```