# Flask app wrapped with DispatcherMiddleware no longer has test_client

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

We can obtain `test_client` for sample application in way like:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        my_app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        cls.client = my_app.app.test_client()
```

However, if we wrap app with `DispatcherMiddleware` - we will get error like
 `AttributeError: 'DispatcherMiddleware' object has no attribute 'test_client'`.

Are there way to test composition of flask applications?

We want to be able to do something like:

```
cls.client = my_app.all_apps.test_client()
```

When `all_apps` is middleware like:

```
all_apps = DispatcherMiddleware(my_app, {
    '/backend': backend_app,
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add WSGI middleware to a Flask app, wrap and replace the app's `wsgi_app` attribute.  You're replacing the reference to the Flask app with a reference to some other WSGI app, which obviously won't have the same properties.  By replacing `wsgi_app`, you retain the reference to the Flask app but change the WSGI callable that backs it.

```
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/backend': backend_app.wsgi_app,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to use the `test_client` on both of the bundled apps. Here is a modification to davidism's answer that allowed me to use test clients for both:

```
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/backend': backend_app.wsgi_app
})
```